# show a div and hide its siblings using href="#id"

Tags: jquery, html, css

I came across this [website](http://saemyon.tumblr.com/symmetry/1) and the way its posts' info shows on click piqued my curiosity.

When `<a class="data-icon-cont">link</a>` is clicked, `<div class="post-data">content</div>` will appear.

How is it possible to show a div - that shares classes with other divs - and hide its siblings using `href="#id"`? Since I'm new to `jquery`, it'd be nice if you'd simplify the answer.

Also, at a look through its source code, this is the jquery code I found. However, due to my lack of knowledge in `jquery`, I can't seem to comprehend the code.

```
$('.data-icon-cont a').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().parent().find(id).fadeIn(0);
    $(this).parent().siblings('.post-data').not(id).fadeOut(0);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Not 100% sure about your question but: `$(this)` inside the click function results the element which is clicked. So even though there are multiple `.data-icon-cont a`, inside the click function  `$(this)` is the specific (and just one) element clicked..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me break the code down from their website in a way that will hopefully help you to create the solution that you're looking for:

```
1. $('.data-icon-cont a').click(function(){ 
2.     var id = $(this).attr('href'); 
3.     $(this).addClass('active');
4.     $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
5.     $(this).parent().parent().find(id).fadeIn(0);
6.     $(this).parent().siblings('.post-data').not(id).fadeOut(0); 
7.     return false 
8.  });
```

1. One line 1, they attached a click handler to the '.data-icon-cont a' elements. A click handler means that it monitors for when this element is clicked and then runs a function. If you're familiar with CSS, this means that it will effect all anchor (a) tags that are inside of an element with the class 'data-icon-cont'. When the click event is fired, the anonymous function in between the curly brackets will run (lines 2 - 7).

   ```
   $('.data-icon-cont a').click(function(){
   ```
2. On line 2, they create a variable and store the name of the ID that we will be searching for in it. They find that variable by checking the href attribute of the element that was clicked.

   ```
   var id = $(this).attr('href');
   ```

Note: $(this) is an object that refers to the element on line 1, the element that was clicked.

3. On line 3, they selected the $(this) object and added the class 'active' to it.

   ```
   $(this).addClass('active');
   ```
4. On line 4, they selected the $(this) element, then they adjusted the selection using the .siblings() function which selected the siblings of the $(this) element. Then removed the class 'active' from those siblings. This ensures that only the clicked element has the class and that it is removed from all the other ones that may have been clicked previously.

   ```
   $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
   ```
5. On line 5, we begin looking for the elements that we want to show or hide. First they select the $(this) element. Then, by using the .parent() function they select it's parent container. Then they used the .parent() function again to select that elements parent container. They now have the grandparent container of the clicked anchor tag selected. This is the container that contains the elements that need to be hidden or shown. So now they search through the elements in that container looking for an element that has an id matching the variable that we fetched on line 2: .find(id). Then they faded it in with 0 marking the duration in miliseconds that the fade will take (It's instant).

   ```
   $(this).parent().parent().find(id).fadeIn(0);
   ```
6. They selected the $(this) element. They moved up one level with the parent() function. They selected all the siblings of that element that have the class 'post-data'. The filtered from that selection the elements that contained the id variable that we fetched on line two. And they faded out the matching elements.

   ```
   $(this).parent().siblings('.post-data').not(id).fadeOut(0);
   ```
7. return false means that the a tag should not fire off it's usual click event. It will only run this function and then stop. The browser will not attempt to navigate anywhere.

   ```
   return false
   ```
8. They closed the function and the click handler that was opened on line 1.

   ```
   });
   ```

If you post HTML code that you're working with specifically, I can provide a specific example. Otherwise, you'll simply need to understand how this example works and modify to fit your own HTML.

Comment: sorry for the very late reply. anywho- thank you for taking the time to explain the code for me, line by line; it sure helps. however, i've tried to remake the effect with jsfiddle and it didn't work. i forgot the link to said fiddle, so i made a quick new one here: http://jsfiddle.net/djubkc05/
any sort of help to make it work would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your fiddle is almost correct. Your selector on line one of the javascript is wrong. You need $('a.data-icon-cont') instead of $('.data-icon-cont a') because in your fiddle you have an anchor tag (<a>) with the data-icon-cont as it's class rather than an anchor tag (<a>) inside of another element with that class.

Answer (score 1):

## Let me guide you through the code.

```
$('.data-icon-cont a')
```

$ is a reference to jQuery itself. (In this case.)
Inside the brackets you can pass in a selector.
Now you can use the outcome this.
In this case:

```
.click(function(){ 

});
```

A Click Handler is attached to every DOM-Element based on the selection above.

```
$(this)
```

inside the click handler function you can access "this". Which gives you the clicked DOM element. To call jQuery methods and other stuff on it it is quite common to wrap "this" in brackets with $ in front of it.
What this does is, make a jQuery-Object of this.
*This is a bit more complicated in detail.*

```
 var id = $(this).attr('href');
```

So what this does is getting the href attribute of thi clicked element and stores that string inside the variable id.

```
$(this).addClass('active');
```

Add class of active to the clicked element.

```
$(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
```

Remove all occurrences of the class active on all siblings of the clicked element.

```
$(this).parent().parent().find(id).fadeIn(0);
```

This is a bit of an overkill but what it does is
**simply**: find the element based on the variable "id" and show it immediately.

**in detail**: it looks for the parent element, and then another parent. Then looks inside for the element, and fades it in in 0ms.

I suggest using this instead:

### $(id).show();

```
$(this).parent().siblings('.post-data').not(id).fadeOut(0);
```

All other elements on the same level are faded out.

```
return false;
```

Prevents the link to be followed. This is not ideal either, but does the job.
There is another way to do this, but that requires a bit more understanding of jQuery and events.  ( **e.preventDefault();** )

Comment: sorry for the very late reply. anywho- thank you for taking the time to explain the code for me, line by line; it sure helps. however, i've tried to remake the effect with jsfiddle and it didn't work. i forgot the link to said fiddle, so i made a quick new one here: http://jsfiddle.net/djubkc05/
any sort of help to make it work would be much appreciated.

Comment: @bloo seems like the selector in your fiddle is not correct. It is describing an a element inside your class. But the a element itself has the class: *a.data-icon-cont*
Btw: please accept an answer and consider upvoting helpful answers and comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(function() {
  $(".data-icon-cont a").on("click", function() {
    var _target = $(this).attr("href").split("#")[1];
    $(".post-data").hide();
    $(".post-data[id=" + _target + "]").show();
  })
})
```

Comment: yip, like that. Be sure to preventDefault there. Good code but I think the question is about understanding how it works

Comment: yes; would you please explain how it works, if it's not too much of a bother? thank you!

Comment: simply, see the below example
<a href="#about-us">about us</a>
<div id="about-us">
........
</div>

you need to show  the <div> which ID = the value in the <a> href
in our example about-us

so when we click on any <a> 
        $(".data-icon-cont a").on("click", function() {
we need to get the value which will be show 
   #about-us
   split this text into two words to get "about-us"
    var _target = $(this).attr("href").split("#")[1];

then hide all divs with class post-data
$(".post-data").hide();
and show only the div with id we need
$(".post-data[id=" + _target + "]").show();